# Gearman worker unresponsive after some time

Tags: php, gearman

I have an php image resizer script running as a Gearman job. Supervisord has been configured to run a resizer worker when started. Now When a user uploads an image, gearmand assigns the job to the worker located on a different machine, which resizes the image and sends it back to the webserver.

The setup works well. The issue is that the script stops functioning after about an hour. The gearman queue shows 1 worker registered, 10 jobs waiting (if I've uploaded 10 images) and 0 jobs running. If I kill the php process running under supervisord, supervisord immediately restarts the process and all my images get resized. 
Could anyone please tell me why the php script stops responding after a certain length of time?

Thanks,
Adi

Comment: I read that as "German worker", I nearly flagged it as inappropriate!

Comment: @Adi: I'd say, you need to look where in that script it hangs. Is it a deadlock in the script or is just PHP hangin'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at version 0.32 or 0.33. Etsy had found a dead lock bug in the server that has now been fixed.

Cheers,
   -Brian

Comment: Could you provide the url about this bug? And which version fix the bug? @Brian Aker